# UTF-8 Unicode encoding and country specific characters

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, char

I'm a bit lost concerning encoding. I do not understand why we say "UTF-8 Unicode". "Unicode" sounds to me like all possible characters in the world, which doesn't fit in a single byte char.

Can you explain this to me please ?

A second question : if i decide to use single byte chars with that "UTF-8 Unicode" encoding in a program, will i be able to handle most european characters ? What about russian, arab, chinese, etc ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're parsing that sentence incorrectly.  "encoding" doesn't modify "UTF-8 Unicode".  "UTF-8" modifies "Unicode encoding".  No one ever says "UTF-8 Unicode", it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks it's a lot clearer now !...

Comment: "Unicode" assigns meaning to numbers. "UTF-8" is a method to express a sequence of numbers as a stream of bytes. Thus UTF-8 *can*, but does not have to be, used to transfer Unicode codepoints as a stream of bytes. More generally, though, UTF-8 (or rather its underlying Thompson scheme) is just a neat way of serializing integers in a variable-width way in which smaller values take up less space, and supporting up to 36-bit values (though Unicode only requires 21).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, I use the term "character" to denote something that can be displayed on a screen and printed on paper by a computer. The official name in Unicode is "code-point". The letter 'a' is a code-point - it is "character" number 97 (0x61), so is a 'ྦྷ' (character 4007, 0xfa7)

Unicode as such encodes just about every known character in every language known on this planet. The coding starts with traditional English/American characters and control character in the first 128 characters (0..127). The next 128 covers a bunch of European letters such as accented and umlauted characters (é, Ä, ö) and some special character  (£, €, etc). Then higher numbers cover "less European" languages such as Russian, Japanese, Chinese, Thai, Urdu, Arabic, Hebrew, etc, etc [I'm not sure exactly in which order these are].

The numbers go into millions.

You can look at the different characters for example [here](http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/).

UTF-8 uses 8 bits per "token". The first 128 characters are encoded straight away as 0..127. Everything else starts with 11xxxxxx in binary. The first character actually tells you how many further characters (up to 5), by using more and more 1's in the beginning, and each subsequent character is encoded as 10xxxxxx. There is ALWAYS a 0 between the last "this is special character" and the "actual data". So for example, a 2-byte combination will have 11*0*xxxxx 10yyyyyy, where xxxxxyyyyyy is the binary code of the character.

UTF-16 works according exactly the same principle, except each "token" is 16 bits. In UTF-16, the range 0xD800-DFFF to encode "longer than 16 bits" encodings. You can read more in the Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (I've not worked much with UTF-16).

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. So how would i be able to use such a byte array with a function expecting a regular string like fopen() ?

Comment: Either `fopen` understands `utf-8`, and you just pass that in. Or it doesn't, in which case you get "garbage" as a filename (it will then encode each byte at a time, so you get whatever 0xC3 0xA0 encodes as in "plain" encoding). And of course, it also relies on anything later on displaying that name to be able to display UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 uses a single byte only for some characters - the basic western alphabet, digits, and punctuation.  Other characters take multiple bytes.

A simple English string like "Hello world!" will take one byte per character.  Include an accented character, as in "Café", and that character will take more than one byte.

The "Description" section of the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) describes it well.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia,

> Unicode is a computing industry standard for the consistent encoding, representation and handling of text expressed in most of the world's writing systems.

UTF-8 is a part of Unicode, it describes an encoding.  It can encode all ~1,000,000 characters in the Unicode standard.  The "8" is there because each character is encoded using a multiple of 8 bits.

For example, "A" is encoded as "41" in hex, "é" is "C3 A9", and "猫" is "E7 8C AB".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what type of char would i use for E7 8C AB then ? wchar_t is only 2 bytes on windows.

Comment: @Virus721: Use arrays of `char` or `unsigned char` for strings.  Use `int` or `unsigned int` for code points.

Comment: @Virus721, wchar_t on Windows is UTF-16 not UTF-8. A single Unicode codepoint can take up to 2 UTF-16 chars.

Comment: I believe it is important to distinguish Unicode code points (which ultimately map to a character) and Unicode code units (which, depending on the encoding -- UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 -- can require several code units to make a single code point).

Comment: Code what ? I'm even more confused now :o

Comment: @Virus721 If you'd read the linked Wikipedia article you wouldn't be so confused.

Comment: Okay so code point => index in the unicode table, and code unit = set of bytes representing the character code right ?

Comment: @Virus721 Right. That difference between the code point ("character index" as you put it) and its representation as a sequence of bytes is really central to the concept of UTF-8/16/32.

Comment: @Virus721: Well, no.  It doesn't compress data, it is just a representation of data.

Comment: Yeah but it only uses 1 byte for ascii chars since the 3 others are not needed

Comment: @Virus721 And yet when writing Chinese (which, I remind you, concerns about 1.5 billion native speakers, a *bit* more than native English speakers) it takes more space than UTF-16, so I wouldn't really call that "compression". ;)

Comment: @Virus721: Compression means reducing the size of the input data representation.  UTF-8 is not compression because there is no input representation to reduce, there is only semantic "data".

Comment: I've read on several XML parser documentations such as this one http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/ that they support UTF-8 Unicode (as it is written). How can they do that, do they use integers as characters ?

Comment: @Virus721: You can write parsers that parse UTF-8 without decoding the code points.

Comment: Actually i'm planing to use one of these XML parsers, but at some point, i will have to retrieve data from the XML parser to use it in my program. So what data type should i use assuming i use UTF-8 ?

Comment: @Virus721: As I said, usually `char` or `unsigned char` for strings of UTF-8.

Comment: But, didn't someone just say that some characters take up to 3 bytes ?

Comment: @Virus721: That's why you use arrays.  A string is an array of `char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yeah but usually 1 char in a string is, well... 1 char.

Comment: @Virus721: That's what you give up when you work with UTF-8: each character might take anywhere from 1 to 4 slots in the array.  The good news is: you won't miss it.  There's hardly ever a good reason to index strings by character when working with Unicode.

Comment: So how can you determine when a new character starts ?

Comment: @Virus721 Once again, **read the Wikipedia article**! It explains everything.

Comment: @Virus721: Read the UTF-8 specification.  It tells you where characters start and stop.  But please don't do something silly like split on character boundaries, or chop the first N characters off a string, because that will mangle the text.

Comment: And how do you interface that way of making a string with functions expecting classical strings like windows's MessageBox() or fopen() or anything ?

Comment: @Virus721: Before you call a Windows API function, convert the UTF-8 string into UTF-16 and use `wchar_t`.  Be sure to `#define UNICODE` before you include any Windows API headers.  Note that UTF-16 / `wchar_t` has the same problems as UTF-8 / `char`: a character might take up two slots in the array.